# i can't add bootstrap carousel in my wordpress query

Tags: wordpress

```
<div class="container post-items">
      <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
          <div class="post-item carousel-inner">
              <ul class="blog carousel-item ">
                  <?php
                  $args = array(
                      'post_type'      => 'post',
                      'posts_per_page' => '4',
                      'cat'         => '3',
                      'orderby'        => 'modified'

                  );
                  ?>
                  <?php
                  $query = new WP_Query($args);
                  while ($query->have_posts()) {

                      $query->the_post(); ?>


                      <li class="blog-grid d-block card" style="width:100%">
                          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a>
                          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium') ?></a>
                      </li>



                  <?php } ?>
              </ul>

          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

i want to show my blog post in carousel way,and i use bootstrap classes in my loop query.but it's not working and doesn't show any thing.could some one help me findout why?

Comment: Question need more informations, such as, did you verify the page source and check that the expected `<li>` tag is rending from a query or not? did you verify if you found posts from the query? what js code you are using? did you try to use dummy carousal HTML to test if carousal works with dummy HTML? did you include the required carousel css and bootstrap js or not?

Comment: i checked li tag it's working

Comment: as soon as i add the bootstrap carousel classes it doesn't show any thing